# Bash script while loop breaks after running another script

Tags: bash

Running another script in bash script while loop runs but the loop breaks!
N.B. The script I mentioned just loops over files in current directory and just run mpirun.
Here's my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
np="$1"
bin="$2"
ref="$3"
query="$4"
word_size="$5"

i=1;
input="$query"
while read line; do
echo $line
  if [[ "${line:0:1}" == ">" ]] ; then
    header="$line"
    echo "$header" >> seq_"${i}".fasta
  else
    seq="$line"
    echo "$seq" >> seq_"${i}".fasta
    if ! (( i % 5)) ; then
        ./run.sh $np $bin $ref $word_size
        ^^^^^^^^
        #for filename in *.fasta; do
        #    mpirun -np "${np}" "${bin}" -d "${ref}" -ql "${filename}" -k "${word_size}" -b > log
        #    rm $filename
        #done
    fi
    ((i++))
  fi
done < $input
```

Comment: When does the loop break? The only way this loop exits is if there is no more data to read from the file named by `$query`.

Comment: It's not the case. there are still lots of lines to be read but after the first time run.sh runs the loop breaks

Comment: Does `run.sh` read from standard input? It inherits its standard input from the loop, so it would consume the rest of the data before `read line` has a chance to execute again.

Comment: no it does not, run.sh just loops over files in current directory and run another program and pass each file to the program that just called by run.sh

Comment: And what does the *other* program do? If it reads from standard input, it is *also* inheriting from `run.sh`  the file `$query` as its standard input (which means, yes, `run.sh` reads from standard input, if only indirectly).

Comment: The other program is mpirun, it just get a binary file location and number of processors and run the binary file in parallel.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, all I can say is *something* in the chain (whether you realize it or not) is reading from `$input`, because an EOF is the only thing in your script that can terminate the loop. You don't have any explicit `break` statements that can terminate it early.

Comment: @chepner was right, `mpirun` [consumes stdin](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/466)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `run.sh` script is passing no parameters to `mpirun`. That script passes the variables `${np} ${bin} ${ref} ${filename} ${word_size}` to `mpirun`, but those variables are local to your main script and are undefined in `run.sh`. You could export those variables in the main script so that they are available to all child processes, but a better solution would be to use positional parameters in `run.sh`:

```
for filename in *.fasta; do
  mpirun -np "${1}" "${2}" -d "${3}" -ql "${4}" -k "${5}" -b > log
  rm $filename
done
```

Comment: Does't work that way either, I say forget the run.sh script, if I call mpirun instead of calling run.sh, mpirun would work properly once and the main while loop breaks after running mpirun But if I call ls command instead of mpirun or run.sh the while loop works and ls would run multiple time.

Comment: Then I suspect that you are passing the parameters to `mpirun` in the wrong order.  Surely you should be passing the command-line options and their values BEFORE you pass the `${bin}` parameter. What happens when you call `mpirun` directly from the command line instead of via this script?

Comment: I think inside his script, `$filename` is an internal variable. So you probably want `mpirun -np "${1}" "${2}" -d "${3}" -ql "${filename}" -k "${4}" -b > log`. There is no `${5}`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `mpirun`, but if you have anything inside your loop that reads from `stdin`, the loop will break.

Comment: So to redirect the stdin you could do e.g.: `./run.sh $np $bin $ref $word_size </dev/null`